# How to correctly add a change in Git

Tags: git, commit

I become a little bit confused by how to add your change to Git safely. My procedure is as follow. Plz let me know if it is wrong or needs modification:

- update code in your local machine

  - git pull & git reset
- make a new branch

  - git branch XYZ & git checkout XYZ
- do your changes and then add to branch staging

  - git add *.txt & git commit - m "XYZ"
- come back to master branch on your local machine

  - git checkout master
- as code in remote repo may have been change since your last pull and therefore your master is not up-to-date:

  - git pull & git reset
- merge the up-to-date master with your branch

  - git merge XYZ
- commit your change to remote repo

  - git pull

Do I need to create any branch after all? what about this:
 (1) update code in your local machine
    * git pull 
 (2) do your changes and then add to branch staging
    * git add *.txt & git commit - m "XYZ"
 (3) as code in remote repo may have been change since your last pull and therefore your master is not up-to-date:
    * git pull
 (4) merge the up-to-date master with your branch
    * git merge
 (5) commit your change to remote repo
    * git pull

Comment: I think you can just git merge without pulling and resetting after checking out master again.

Comment: To be pedantic you push changes to remote repo rather than commit them. And `git push` instead of `git pull` to push to remote.

Comment: Did you get this sorted out? Please consider accepting an answer if your question was answered.

Answer (score 1):

Close but there are some commands you're doing unnecessarily -- like the resets. From the workflow you've described this is in general what you'll do.

```
// this part creates a new branch from the most updated master
git fetch origin
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout -b XYZ // creates a new branch XYZ

// do your work

// this part adds your files and commits to your XYZ branch
git add *file* // I recommend that you add files one at a time
git commit -m "My Commit Message" // the message doesn't have to have a connection to branch XYZ

// before you push up to origin again make sure your XYZ branch has the latest master code
git fetch origin
git pull origin master // fix any merge conflicts after this step

// push your XYZ branch up to origin
git push origin XYZ

// at this point there is usually some type of peer code review or QA process before any new changes are merged into master.
// Assuming, the branch and its changes are approved then you would merge to master like so:

git fetch origin
git checkout master
git pull origin master //sync master again in case there have been new changes
git merge XYZ
git push origin master
```

Some may say that the `git fetch origin` commands are superfluous for this workflow, but I think it's always good to keep your remote tracking branches up to date.

Comment: what about - git checkout master and - git merge XYZ after and before the second git fetch/pull?

Comment: Not sure what your team's exact process is but you probably shouldn't merge your changes directly into master until after there has been peer code-review and/or some type of QA process. In general this is why you are doing your work in a separate branch -- to allow for this type of audit before a merge into master. Ultimately, this totally depends on your team's workflow. I'll update my answer to reflect my comments.

Comment: It is a small team. So, there is no code-review and QA. I need to push everything to master and I guess branching is not necessary after all. However, would like to know the flow without branching considering the code in repo may change till your first pull and your commit.

Comment: The flow without branching is basically the same as above except that you don't create a new branch. Just checkout master, make sure it's synced up then make your changes. Afterwards, pull master again then push it up. The `master` branch is just a regular branch like every other branch. The only thing that makes it special is that we say it is special.

Answer (score 1):

That seems very excessive and I'm not sure why you're `reset`ing every time.

The general steps I follow are:

- `checkout` branch I want to work on (`pull` here to make sure it's up to date)
- make the changes I want to make
- if remote branch has changed while I was working, `pull` and merge any changes
- `add` changes to local index
- `commit` local changes locally
- `push` changes to remote repo

Comment: don't you need indexing changes like `add` or/and `stage` before commit?

Comment: @GermanPetrov, yes I bundled that in with the commit locally step - probably wasn't the clearest way of putting it. I'll add that explicitly.

Comment: so, you mean only the reset part is unnecessary?

Comment: Creating a new branch for every change/commit could be a bit over the top although it depends what changes you're making.